# Android App Internal Data Storage

Tags: java, android, arrays, file-io, storage

I am attempting to save an array of longs as a text file using the Android's internal memory, and then access that array in a different activity. After noticing that was broken, I isolated the problem in this chunk of code below.

```
long[] timings = {200, 400, 600, 1400};
try {
    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("timings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
    osw.write(Arrays.toString(timings));        
    osw.close();

    FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("timings");
    InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(fis);
    char[] buffer = new char[timings.length];
    isReader.read(buffer);

    textField.setText(Arrays.toString(buffer));

    fis.close();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

The text field that is set to display what is read from the file has the following result:

```
[[,2,0,0]
```

The result I expected was the original array from above. What am I doing wrong here? Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: why you want to store longs in a file ?? you can use other mechanisms for that na!! like sqlite database/ make some static class or use application class !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this :

```
        InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        char[] buffer = new char[timings.length];
        isReader.read(buffer);

        textField.setText(Arrays.toString(buffer));
```

with this :

```
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fis);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String sTemp1 = "", sTemp2 = "";
        while ((sTemp1 = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sTemp2 = sTemp1;
        }
        in.close();

        textField.setText(sTemp2);
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was quite helpful.